# How to make sure user enter valid switch case option?

Tags: linux, shell, switch-statement, sh

Im trying to figure out how to fix this code...

```
echo -n "Enter you complaint : ";
read complaint;


if [[ -z $complaint ]] || [[ $complaint != 'FIRE' ]] || [[ $complaint != 'INTOXICATION' ]] || [[ $complaint != "INJURY" ]] || [[ $complaint != "BREAKAGE" ]] ;then
    echo "Not a good option";
    exit 1;
fi


case $complaint in
    FIRE)  = $complaint=$(echo "FIRE");;
    INTOXICATION) = $complaint=$(echo "INTOXICATION");;
    INJURY) = $complaint=$(echo "INJURY");;
    BREAKAGE) = $complaint=$(echo "BREAKAGE");;
esac
```

Is it possible to know :
Why does it always enter in the if even if im typing a valid thing?

Comment: If a string is `FIRE`, then it is not `INTOXICATION`. If it is `INTOXICATION`, then it is not `FIRE`. If it is anything else, then it is not `FIRE`. (One of these two will always be true.)

Comment: Ok but, how do I make sure the user is typing a valid thing switch case option?

Comment: You will have to test the negation: `cond1 && cond2 && ...`

Comment: What does `$(echo "FIRE")` achieve that `"FIRE"` doesn't do except not work if you don't have `echo`?

Comment: It's just a question of curiosity so I made the example really quick but, yeah that's a pretty stupid thing for me to do.

Comment: What is `= $complaint=$(echo "FIRE")` supposed to *do*? `= $complaint="FIRE"` would be more efficient, but just as broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the `if` is wrong, it should be:

```
if [[ -z $complaint ]] || [[ ( $complaint != 'FIRE' && $complaint != 'INTOXICATION' && $complaint != "BRIS" && $complaint != "BOBO" ) ]] ;then
```

That is, you want to go inside that `if` if `$complaint` is `null` (`-z $complaint`) or if it doesn't match any of the valid options, so it has to be different to all of them at the same time, thus the `&&` instead of `||`.

Alternatively, you can also use a default condition in the [`case...esac`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/case-esac-statement.htm) block:

```
case $complaint in
    FIRE)  = $complaint=$(echo "FIRE");;
    INTOXICATION) = $complaint=$(echo "INTOXICATION");;
    INJURY) = $complaint=$(echo "INJURY");;
    BREAKAGE) = $complaint=$(echo "BREAKAGE");;
    *) echo "Not a good option"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks man! but do you know the answer for my second question?

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r Ups, sorry, I didn't see that part. I'm not familiar with `awk` thought. Maybe you can get the fields you need from `whoami`, `date` and `hostname -I`.